# How to check whether a file/chunk is all zeros

Tags: python, python-3.x, filesystems, bitstring

I have written some software that reads a proprietary file system's index and then writes the files to a new location (see [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/182773/reading-a-proprietary-file-system-and-creating-files) for more info if interested).

Since successfully using the software, I have noticed that some blocks pointed at by the file system actually contain no data anymore and are filled with zeros.  The way I've written the software so far results in zero byte files being written to the length of the default block size of the file system (typically 1GB).

I'd like an efficient method for checking whether a block is entirely filled with zeros before it is written as a file.  My first idea is to simply use the find function of bitstring to look for a 1 bit and then to return True that the block has data.

Is there a more efficient method?

Comment: `any(map(int, bitstring))`

Comment: @StefanPochmann sorry Stefan I should have been referring to blocks and not chunks.  The chunk is my own reference for writing the file in chunks.  The block size is determined by the file system I am reading from and is typically 1GB.

Comment: I guess you could map to bool too.

Comment: @ChristoferOhlsson I will give that method a go, it seems to make sense having read up on the two functions. Thanks

Comment: @ChristoferOhlsson Hmm... `any(bitstring)` doesn't work? (I'm not familiar with `bitstring`)

Comment: I'm sorry, I was being unclear. I meant for `bitstring` to refer to the string of bits you were using. But maybe I misunderstood your implementation.

Comment: I am using a module called bitstring (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitstring/3.1.3).  Unfortunately, i'm not sure bitstring (the module) will be the best way to go here.  The bitstring in my code is the entire hard drive (typically 1tb/2tb) and creating a 1gb slice takes a huge amount of time (45minutes-ish).